# How to click cssSelector in webdriverio

Tags: node.js, selenium, xpath, webdriver-io

I have a page in a Lightening SalesForce application that I need to click. 
I have tried copying it's xpath, but webdriver IO cannot find this element nor interact with it.

Here is it's HTML:

```
<span class=" listViewPickerOption" data-aura-rendered-by="1124:0">All Accounts</span>
```

I have tried this in my webdriverIO code:

```
.click('//*[@id="800:0_listviewpicker_0"]/span[3]')
```

`(//*[@id="800:0_listviewpicker_0"]/span[3]` is the xpath of the element.

when I run the test, it does not click on this element.

What is the correct way to click on this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

this is what ended up working 100% of the time:

```
.click('//span[text()="All Accounts"]')
```

It clicks on this element every time without fail.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is something like this:
//*[@class="listViewPickerOption"]

If I'm understanding the question correctly, that should do it. You can test out xpath in the developer tools of chrome when you do a search on the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, HTML elements are nested under a `<frame>` or an `<iframe>` element.
The Webdriver does not automatically read inside these frames, so you'll have to switch to the frame for the webdriver to be able to read the internal HTML.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("whatever the frame name is");
```

Comment: it is not in a frame -- It's a SalesForce application and not straght forward HTML